# will changes from trunk still merge into a renamed file?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, file-rename

Assume I copy `^/trunk` to `^/branches/test` and now I rename a file in `test` from `fileA.c` to `fileB.c` using `svn mv`. Now my question is, will changes that get applied to `^/trunk/fileA.c` still merge into `^/branches/test/fileB.c` when using `svn merge ^/trunk` (from within `branches/test/` directory)?

**EDIT 1**
So, if a file got renamed in my branch as described above, will a new `svn mv` to rename it back to its original name put things back in order?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Even worse: if the same (formerly) object was renamed and edited on different sides of merge after branchpoint at the same time, you'll get famous "Tree Conflict" on merge-attempt

Comment: Oh, okay, please see **EDIT 1** above